# Use picinpar instead of wrapfigure for LaTeX-export

Tags: org-export, latex

Org-mode exports to `wrapfigure` with `ATTR_LATEX: :float wrap`.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47674/wrapfig-positioning-footer-is-overlapping-figure?noredirect=1&lq=1 recommends to use `picins` instead. How can the environment be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but: Reconsider if you really want to  wrap them. Even for plain LaTeX, [the wikibooks LaTeX manual](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures) recommends:

> A word of warning: Wrapping figures in LaTeX will require a lot of manual adjustment of your document. There are several packages available for the task, but none of them works perfectly. Before you make the choice of including figures with text wrapping in your document, make sure you have considered all the options. For example, you could use a layout with two columns for your documents and have no text-wrapping at all.

https://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-1/mori/mori.pdf recommends to set `org-latex-default-figure-position` to `tb` and let LaTeX do its job.

> The only thing that the author should determine is
>   whether the object is small enough to appear on a page with other text or will
>   require a whole page to itself. In the first case the best option is [tb], in the
>   second [p].

Adjusting `org-latex-default-image-width` to a smaller size could help, too.